# Custom filter for jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid and want to create complex filter by 2 columns together: Country & City.
I have list of Countries and each Country have 1-5 Cities + Select All + Any.
I need something like that:

[image]

Is it possible to do using standard jqGrid filter (if yes - how?) or may be you can give the most closer solution to it?

Comment: Where you want to create the filter - when using filter Toolbar or when using form searching?

Comment: I want this filter by clicking on Country column in jqGrid: appearing list of countries with list of cities in each of them.